# How to make my navbar stay in front of the slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfiLZ.jpg

How do I make the navbar responsive, in front of the div, which is the slideshow with images ?

I tried to put the div inside the main, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, in order to help others who read this post (either to help  you or someone in the future that could learn from this) please post code examples here, not pictures. Also, please be more descriptive of what exactly are you wanting to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend in the future to post your pictures and code directly here in your question. But to help, you would need to specify a `z-index` in CSS. This indicates foreground-background on your website. Just make sure you set a position in CSS also. For instance:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```